# How to clear terminal window after TMOUT

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I want to see if there is a way to have the terminal windows cleared after a TMOUT session timeout and disconnect. Does anyone know of a way to have the screen cleared once it times out?

Comment: Does the shell log out? Does `.bash_logout` work for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an exit trap in your `.bashrc` file

```
trap '[[ -n $TMOUT ]] && clear' exit
```

When the shell exits, it executes the `clear` command if `TMOUT` is set to a non-null value.

Comment: OP seems to be asked for this to happen in the event of a timeout.  Having the variable set does not guarantee that was the reason for the exit.